# Android Talkback reads everything in the system language

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I'm working on an application which supports 2 languages: dutch & french
If you have your device set in English, talkback reads all texts in the default talkback language
on iOS you have the "accessibilityLanguage" property, but I don't seem to find an equivalent in the android API
Things I've found and tried:

- LocaleSpan: works, but I can't imagine it's the goal to wrap every single text manually in a LocaleSpan? I think it's rather meant for texts in a different language then your app language
- TextView.textLocale: not sure what it does, didn't see/hear anything different

Is this behaviour of talkback normal? Seems "wrong" to me, but I'm not a TalkBack user myself so I'm not sure, but it's very difficult to listen to the dutch text in an english accent.